# Prove that the functions $F$ and $G$ which have same domain and range are equal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

The question is stated as: Consider any functions $F$ and $G$. Prove that, if

- $F$ and $G$ have the same domain $A$,
- For any $x$ in $A$, $F(x) = G(x)$,

Then $F=G$ (Hint: Show that $(x,y) \in F \Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in G$)

Here is my atempt:

First assume for some arbitrary $x$, that $(x,y) \in F$, as $F$ and $G$ have the same domain $A$, we have that some $(x,z) \in G$.

But we have that $(\forall x)(F(x) = G(x)$, thus $y=z$ and therefore $((x,y) \in F \Rightarrow (x,y) \in G)$, and as $x$ is arbitrary we have that $(\forall x)((x,y) \in F \Rightarrow (x,y) \in G)$, and following the same process the converse is true too thus.

$$(\forall x)[((x,y) \in F \Rightarrow (x,y) \in G) \land ((x,y) \in G \Rightarrow (x,y) \in F)]$$
$$(x,y) \in F \Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in G$$
$$F = G$$

I think im missing something, but when i read the two assumption from the question it seems obvious that they need to be the same function, but I need to get it right because this concept seems to be very useful when proving uniqueness and in other proves as well.

Comment: You might be feeling like this argument is trivial, and it's because you're right; the argument is trivial (your proof is correct as far as I can see).

Comment: So whenever I need to prove equality of function, like when dealing with proofs of operation definition, the logic will be same? I will need to show that "some have a ordered pair iff the other have this ordered pair"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "proofs of operation definition" but in the wild you'll almost exclusively show equality of functions by showing $F(x)=G(x)$ for all $x$. The representation of a function as a set of ordered pairs is pretty much just a formality to show that "functions can be defined in set theory"

Comment: I was trying to talk about when someone is trying to prove some operation is well defined and unique on some set, eg: multiplication on natural numbers.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case I'll still stand by what I said about using ordered pairs as being too pedantic; showing a function is well-defined amounts to showing that $f(x)$ exists for all $x$ in the domain and $f(x)=f(x')$ whenever $x=x'$, and showing a function is unique amounts to showing for any other $g$ satisfying your rules that $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with the question, and also something wrong with your attempt. Firstly, in normal mathematics there is simply no reason to use any specific *encoding* of functions in the underlying foundational system. Hence we simply **define** that for any functions $F,G$ we have $F = G$ iff there is some set $A$ such that $F,G$ have domain $A$ and $F(x) = G(x)$ for every $x∈A$.

So in normal mathematics the question is meaningless. If you wish to work in a foundational theory instead, where a function on $A$ is defined a subset of $A×B$ for some set $B$, and treat equality of functions as equality of sets, then you still have to define what you mean by the function-application notation "$F(x)$". This is not a trivial matter, so the question still has a problem. Think about it a little. Do you want it to mean $\bigcup \{ y : ⟨x,y⟩∈F \}$? Or how about $\{ z : ⟨x,y⟩∈F ∧ z∈y \}$? Both work, but are different. And yet neither showed up in your question...

Another option is to treat only *entire predicates* involving "$F(x)$" as short-hand for a longer predicate given by a syntactic transformation. For instance, "$F(x) = G(x)$" is interpreted as "$∀z,w\ ( (x,z)∈F ∧ (x,w)∈G ⇒ z=w )$". This is one standard approach in a foundational treatment of functions, but then your attempt is incorrect. If you want to see this approach properly done, you would need to prove the following for any functions $F,G$:

> $∀A\ ( \ ∃S\ ( \ F⊆A×S \ ) ∧ ∃T\ ( \ G⊆A×T \ )$
> $\ ∧ ∀x{∈}A\ ∀z,w\ ( \ (x,z)∈F ∧ (x,w)∈G ⇒ z=w \ )$
> $\ ⇒ F=G \ )$.

In this approach, this is the true symbolic expansion of:

> $∀A\ ( \ dom(F) = dom(G) = A ∧ ∀x{∈}A\ ( \ F(x) = G(x) \ ) ⇒ F=G \ )$.

Comment: [1/2]
I dont know if I understood your examples of possible $F(x)$ definitions, the first one $\bigcup \{\{y\} : (x,y) \in F \}$ seems to be the set builded by the application of $F$ in the entire domain such$\{y : (x,y) \in F\}$ or $\{ F(x) : x \in A \}$, and the later one $\{z : (x,y) \in F \land z \in y\}$ dont make sense for me at all, If it was $\{z : (x,y \in F \land z = y)\}$ then it will be equal to the other definition. If a interpreted it right in both cases we got the range set with those definitions, The simple definition I have found in the book im following is:

Comment: [2/2]
Let $R(x)$ be the range of set $x$.
$$y \in R(F) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x)((x,y) \in F)$$
$$y \in R(F) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x)(F(x)=y)$$
In a textual way: For each element $x$ of the domain of $F$, there is one and only one object $y$ such that $(x,y) \in F$. This unique object shall be denoted $F(x)$. Its called the value of $F$ for the argument $x$. What I tried to do is to use the standard approach in a foundational treatment of functions, but you said its incorrect, It is incorrect because because I should begin from the last expression you you gave?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim: "$\bigcup S$" is standard notation denoting the union of all members of $S$, but I made a silly careless mistake in my post, so let me fix it before addressing your other questions in your comment.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim: The statements you quote from your textbook do not actually say "there is one and only one object $y$". In fact, it is flawed, because it uses the notation "$F(x)$" without defining it. It **implicitly** assumes that when $F$ is a function and $x$ is in the domain of $F$ we can write "$F(x)$" and it refers to a unique object $y$ such that $(x,y)∈F$. This means that it treats this notation as a *term-forming* syntax. In this case, you still need something like the last point in my first paragraph, namely that you need to define what "$F=G$" means.

Comment: If you wish to define it as set equality, then the whole thing rests on the **prior** definition of "function" for it to be meaningful to say "when F is a function". In particular, you would need to define that $F$ is a function iff $∀x,y\ ( \ ⟨x,y⟩∈F ⇒ ∀z\ ( \ ⟨x,z⟩∈F ⇒ y=z \ ) \ )$. And then **that** is what you need to use to prove the desired claim, not what you did.

Comment: I miss to provide the definition of function whithe book gave, it is:
"By a function we mean a relation $F$ having the additional property":
$$[(x,y) \in F \land (x,z) \in F] \Rightarrow y = z$$

Comment: That's equivalent, yes. I also fixed the last part of my answer; sorry for careless mistakes. As I said, for normal mathematics you should stick with what I stated in the first paragraph. If you want to go to the underlying set theory, you must do it properly. To prove that $F = G$ here you would have to prove $∀t \ ( t∈F ⇔ t∈G )$. To start: Take any functions $F,G$ with domain $A$. Take any $t∈F$. Then $t=⟨x,y⟩$ for some $x∈A$. Since $x$ is in the domain of $G$, there is some $z$ such that $⟨x,z⟩∈G$. Since $F,G$ are functions, we have $y = F(x) = G(x) = z$. Thus .. Similarly take any $t∈G$..

Comment: I think I got the point, if my interpretation are correct my error is to never take in account the definition of function in my proof, I think the begin of my proof is correct but i completly missed the function definiction, let me know if Im missing something more.

Please consider adding your last comment as and edit to your own answer.

Comment: Let me ask another thing, when you say "we have $y = F(x) = G(x) = z$", it comes from  your conclusion that $(x,y) \in F$ and $(x,z) \in G$ and on the assumption from question which says $(\forall x)(F(x) = G(x))$ ?

Comment: Yes. First and last equality are from the definition of function and the term-forming syntax. Middle equality is from the assumption as you stated.